# KnockoutJS selectedOptions not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS to manage my web front-end.  I am writing a CRUD/Admin site, but I am having problems with the selectedOptions binding.

The case:

- The view model has `form.products.all` and `form.products.selected` observables.  Both of these are generated by `ko.mapping`.
- The HTML form has a multi-select of the form:

  ```
  <select required="" multiple="" data-bind="options: products.all, optionsText: function (item) { return item.value.name.unName(); }, selectedOptions: products.selected" class="form-control">
  ```
- The HTML form correctly shows all the options.
- The HTML form does **not** show the selected options on load.  In particular, if I inspect the viewModel object, I can see that the right objects get loaded into the `products.selected` array on load.  But the multi-select does not select them automatically.
- If I select objects in the form and then inspect the `products.selected` observable, I **do** see the objects in the array.
- If I post the form, the right objects end up in the database, and then end up in the viewModel object on the next page load (so the only part missing in the cycle is actually marking the form based on what is in `products.selected`.

What am I doing wrong?  I've seen conflicting advice, and some of it is outdated, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The documentation says "Likewise, assuming it’s an observable array on your view model, then whenever you add or remove (e.g., via push or splice) items to this array, the corresponding items in the UI become selected or deselected. It’s a 2-way binding."

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or something of the kind?

Comment: @nomen you right ignore my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selectedOptions` binding works as designed.

Your error is very likely that your `selected` observable does not contain the *identical* objects (i.e., *references* to the objects in `all`), but merely objects that have equal property values.

Knockout maintains the binding through object identity, it does not make any other comparisons.

Consider this simple example:

```js
var vm = {
    products: {
        selected: ko.observableArray(),
        all: ko.observableArray([
            {
                value: {
                    name: {
                        unName: ko.observable("Foo")
                    }
                }
            }, {
                value: {
                    name: {
                        unName: ko.observable("Bar")
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
    }
};
vm.products.selected.push(vm.products.all()[1]);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
pre {
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select required="" multiple="" class="form-control" data-bind="
    options: products.all, 
    optionsText: function (item) { 
        return item.value.name.unName(); 
    }, 
    selectedOptions: products.selected
"></select>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

---

Unrelated side-note: Try to avoid defining functions in the binding attribute. It's ugly, inefficient, potentially repetitive and not very idiomatic. Make a corresponding property on the view model, for example like this:

```
function Product(data) {
    ko.utils.extend(this, data);
    this.displayName = this.value.name.unName;
}
```

and

```html
<div data-bind="with: products">
    <select required="" multiple="" class="form-control" data-bind="
        options: all, 
        optionsText: 'displayName', 
        selectedOptions: selected
    "></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that does make sense.  Presumably, the solution is to customize the `ko.mapping` object creation for both `products.all` and `products.selected` (i.e., to marshal them both to a viewModel specific representation)

Comment: Yes, for example. Assuming you receive both lists from the server, I'd first map all products into `products.all`, building an index in the process. Next I'd iterate the `selected` products, pick the corresponding instances from the index and push them into `products.selected`.

Comment: finally... this was so frustrating. Good answer, especially since you explained the difference between identical objects and objects with merely equal property values.